# ATS iOS 9: how to enable MAMP to TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, https, mamp, ios9, tls1.2

Up to few days ago I was developing my iOS 8 app but this morning my XCode updated to version 7 and iOS simulator to iOS 9. So, in order to meet iOS9 ATS requirements I must update MAMP so that it supports TLS 1.2 and the other requirements. Up to now I haven't found anything useful to me, so I would like to ask if you can explain me hot to set MAMP in order to support iOS9 ATS and TLS 1.2. The URLs my app is trying to use are like the following:

```
https://localhost:443/excogitoweb/mobile/loginM.php
```

They perfectly work if I type them in a browser but if I run my app I get this:

```
2015-09-21 20:55:10.217 ExcogitoWeb[3848:34387] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-09-21 20:55:10.218 ExcogitoWeb[3848:34387] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

so either I am making a mistake in MAMP configuration of I have missed something but I don't know what. This is what I've done up to now:

- create a self signed certificate with sha256 running

  openssl req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt

And configure my httpd-ssl.conf file where I've tried enabling also Forward Secrecy ciphers as required from ATS

In my httpd-ssl.conf file I have something like:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protected"
  ServerName localhost
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
      SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have  configured in the same way. 
So, when I run my app it crashes with the error mentioned above, the error code 9824  which, according to what I have read here, means an error about TLS protocol handshaking. So I am afraid my MAMP 3.3 free in not running TLS 1.2.

Would someone please help me and tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks to all for your attention

**UPDATE**
I've just tried with

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2
```

and now the Apache server won't start anymore. Nothing is written on the log. Do I need to update ssl on my MAC Yosemite? How?

Anyway, restoring with

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

this is what I get from my browser if I type https://localhost

[image]

so MAMP still uses TLS 1.0... is there a way to force it?